Google adsense integration problem on iisnode
I have implemented Google AdSense in my Next.js project. When I deploy the project on Vercel, the AdSense implementation works perfectly, and I can successfully verify it in my Google AdSense account.
However, when I deploy the same project using IISNode on a Windows Server, Google AdSense fails to validate. The AdSense script is added correctly to the  of my application, but it does not pass the verification process on Google AdSense.
Details:
The project works as expected when hosted on Vercel.
On the Windows Server, I'm using IISNode to serve the Next.js application.
The site is publicly accessible and uses HTTPS.
The AdSense code snippet is identical in both deployments.
Question:
What could cause Google AdSense to fail validation when using IISNode on a Windows Server, but work seamlessly on Vercel? Are there any specific configurations or settings I need to adjust in IIS or IISNode to resolve this issue?
What I’ve Tried:
Verified the site is publicly accessible and not blocked by any firewalls.
Checked the robots.txt file to ensure Googlebot has access.
Ensured HTTPS is properly set up.
Confirmed the AdSense script is included in the  of the application.
